# Convert from base class to a dervied class

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert from a base class to a derived class.
I have the following constructor, however, the compiler complains with:

```
no matching function for call to ‘baseObject::baseObject()’
```

constructor:

```
derivedObject(const baseObject &base, const std::string &extra1)
{
    baseparameter1 = base.baseparameter1;
    baseparameter2 = base.baseparameter2;
    extraparameter1 = extra1;
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: Looks like your class `baseObject` doesn't have a default constructor. can we see `baseObject`?

Comment: That is correct, but why does it need to have one. The baseobject that I am passing should have been already constructed

Comment: The constructor of a derived object will automatically call the constructor of its base class. This isn't because the `baseObject` your passing in, this is because of the `derivedObject` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every constructor begins by initializing all base classes and direct members, before you get to the `{`.  Instead of using assignments in the body, use a member initializer list:

```
derivedObject(const baseObject &base, const std::string &extra1)
    : baseObject(base),        // Calls the baseObject copy constructor
      extraParameter1(extra1)  // Initialize the direct member
{
}
```

This is better style and also avoids problems like the one you ran into.

Comment: ahh thanks! quick question though, do I have to create my own copy constructor, or does the default one copy the data members for me?

Comment: @marcwho If the class does not declare any copy constructor member, the compiler will automagically add one that is `public` and copies each base class and member.  This is usually good enough (but see the Rule Of Three).

Answer (score 2):

**edit**: `baseObject` copy construction.

Since you haven't defined a default constructor for your `baseObject`, the compiler can't construct a `derivedObject` without an explicit specification for which `baseObject` constructor to use.

In your definition of the `derivedConstructor`, then, you're going to need to specify exactly the `baseObject` constructor.  Since I have no idea what your `baseObject` looks like, I've used a placeholder below:

```
derivedObject(const baseObject &base, const std::string &extra1)
    : baseObject(PARAM1, PARAM2)
{
    baseparameter1 = base.baseparameter1;
    baseparameter2 = base.baseparameter2;
    extraparameter1 = extra1;
}
```

---

In your particular case, if you're trying to create a `derivedObject` from a `baseObject` that already exists, you should define `baseObject`'s copy constructor, and do as follows:

```
derivedObject(const baseObject &base, const std::string &extra1)
    : baseObject(base)
{
    baseparameter1 = base.baseparameter1;
    baseparameter2 = base.baseparameter2;
    extraparameter1 = extra1;
}
```

Comment: I suspect the latter sample is likely what the OP is driving toward.